Encountering 'Cannot POST' Error When Attempting to Upload Screenshots via Form Data Posting - How to Resolve?
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to upload screenshots via form data posting in my React application. Here's the scenario:
I have a simple React form that collects data from users, including a file input field for uploading screenshots. Upon submission, the form data is sent to my Node.js backend server, which is built with Express.js, to be processed and stored in a database table.
However, when I submit the form, instead of successfully uploading the data and screenshots, I'm greeted with a 'Cannot POST' error screen. This error disrupts the intended flow of my application
// this the form code
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const App = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState('');
  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('/api/data', { data: formData });
      console.log(response.data);
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log('Error: ', error);
    }

  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" value={formData} onChange={(e) => setFormData(e.target.value)} /><br />
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;re

// this is the backend code
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const app = express();
const port = 3001;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Create connection to the database
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '', // Enter your MySQL Password here
    database: 'mydb'
});

connection.connect();

//Create operation (POST)
app.post('/api/data', (req, res) => {
    const { data } = req.body;
    const sql = 'INSERT INTO mytable(Name)value(?)';
    connection.query(sql, [data], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error inserting data", err);
            res.status(500).json({ err: 'Failed to insert data' });
            return;
        }
        console.log('Data inserted: ', result);
        res.json({ message: 'Data inserted successfully.' });
    });
});
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));


You need to set base url for axios.

const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/data', { data: formData });

Or you need to set proxy in frontend to connect to backend 3001 port.
like this in package.json file add this below code.
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"

